# Issue with Passing Data to Apex Class from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to pass the data to Apex class from LWC, here is the code:

```
import getIPData from '@salesforce/apex/InvokeIPController.getIPData';
....
@api
invokeIPData() {

    let IPDetails = {
        Name : 'LWC_SampleData',
        inputMap : {},
        options : {}
    }

    getIPData(IPDetails)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                this.contacts = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });
    return null;
}
```

In the Apex Class, I have :

```
public with sharing class InvokeIPController {

@AuraEnabled
public static Object getIPData(Map<String, Object> procedureDetails){
    System.debug('procedureName : ' + procedureDetails);
    ....
}
```

The `procedureDetails` is coming as null. May I know what am I missing here? I believe something wrong in the way I'm passing the data to Apex Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters object is an object, not a list of parameters:

```
getIPData({ procedureDetails: IPDetails })
```

Note that procedureDetails is the case-sensitive name of the parameter name, and IPDetails is the case-sensitive name of the variable that contains the data. This is demonstrated in the [trailhead module on Github](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams).

> ```
>     findContacts({ searchKey: this.searchKey })
>         .then(result => {
>             this.contacts = result;
>             this.error = undefined;
>         })
>         .catch(error => {
>             this.error = error;
>             this.contacts = undefined;
>         });
> ```

Comment: That worked like a charm..!!